# Jumbotron color and background won't change

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

trying to change the background and color of my jumbotron and nothing happens.
The `padding` works, but the `background` does not.

My CSS:

```
.jumbotron {
    padding:70px 30px 70px 30px;
    margin:0px auto;
    background: #7986CB ;
    color:blue;
}

.row-header{
    margin:0px auto;
    padding:0px auto;
}
```

My `<body>`:

```
<header class="jumbotron">
        <div class="container">
            <div class="row row-header">
                <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-8">
                    <h1>Header</h1>
                    <p style="padding:40px;"></p>
                    <p>bla bla</p>
                </div>
                <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-4">
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </header>
```

Why won't the collor change to blue, or the background to #7986CB?
The inclusion of the CSS is ok, since changing the paddings *does* affect the jumbotron.

Comment: I think it works fine https://jsfiddle.net/2Lzo9vfc/593/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

use:

```
    background-color : #222 !important;
```

**Update:**
This is not a good way to override a style as it overrides every other `background-color` (except those that are specified in the inline `style` attribute). Try increasing the specificity of the CSS selector rather than using `!important`.
Read more about specificity here:
https://css-tricks.com/specifics-on-css-specificity/

Answer (score 4):

Because you're directly overriding Bootstrap's CSS, you'll need to use the same syntax as they do:

```
.jumbotron {
  background-color: #7986CB;
}
```

Alternatively, you can add `!important` to force the override, but this is not recommended.

Using Developer Tools it's easy to see which CSS is applied and to which rules. Valid rules that are not applied are crossed out.

Comment: Thanks! the `!important` thing worked. changing to `background-color` did not though

Answer (score 2):

Your CSS Link has to be below the Bootstrap Link.

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/css/bootstrap.min.css"> <--Bootstrap-->
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="app.css"> <--User_Defined-->
```

Answer (score 1):

The way I see it,  it should work so make sure your css link is below the bootstrap or else the default bootstrap styles would keep overriding your css.

Answer (score 0):

Use a *custom class* for specificity if need be, you don't need to use **!important** for something so simple. See [MDN Specificity](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Specificity).

**Working Example:**

```css
.jumbotron.jumbotron-blue {
  background: #7986CB;
  color: blue;
  padding: 70px 30px;
  margin: 0;
}
.jumbotron.jumbotron-blue h1 {
  margin: 0;
}
.heading-paragraph {
  padding-top: 70px;
  margin: 0;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<header class="jumbotron jumbotron-blue">
  <div class="container">
    <h1>This is a Heading</h1>
    <p class="heading-paragraph">Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It
    </p>
  </div>
</header>

<div class="well">Hello</div>
```